# Play 2 Scala - controller does not see model and view

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to create my first project using Play2 and Scala.

Unfortunately, my controller does not see my model and my view.

Controller:

```
package controllers

import models.WikiArticle
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    val wikiArticle = new WikiArticle("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=George%20Washington&redirects=true");
    wikiArticle.queryApi();
    var text = wikiArticle.getText();
    Ok(views.html.index(text))
  }

}
```

Model:

```
package models

import play.api.libs.ws.{WSRequest, WS}
import play.api.Play.current


class WikiArticle(url : String) {

  var text : WSRequest = null

  def queryAPI(): Unit = {
    text = WS.url(url)
  }

  def getText(): WSRequest = {
    return text
  }

}
```

View:

```
@(text: String)

<div>
    @text
</div>
```

I am getting the following errors in my Controller.
Where I access the model:

```
Error:(11, 17) value queryApi is not a member of models.WikiArticle
    wikiArticle.queryApi();
```

Where I access the view:

```
Error:(13, 19) object index is not a member of package views.html
    Ok(views.html.index(text))
              ^
            ^
```

**EDIT**
I changed the signature of wikiArticle.queryApi()

Comment: As suggested, did you match exact name (including case of queryApi): queryApi is not a member, but queryAPI is. Also, excuse dumb question but what is the location/name of your view? Should be in views and named index.scala.html...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call without parameters:

```
wikiArticle.queryApi();
```

while you have defined queryApi as function with parameter:

```
def queryAPI(url: String)
```

Also, note upper/lower case

Comment: Thank you! However, even after changing that, I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Note upper/lower case